# How to create custom common JSON message format for Java JAX-RS services?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I am creating a web application in Java and I want to completely divide the frontend from the server part. Therefore everything is going to be implemented via services, particularly JSON Rest services. I want to have a common message format, something like this (for convenience I write it as XML, but am going to use JSON - should be a matter of configuration anyway):

```
<response>
    <time>...</time>
    <status>
        <code></code>
        <message></message>
    </status>
    <data>
        ...my entities resulting from the operations...
    </data>
</response>
```

My question is how to implement and use this custom format in my methods universally? That means, that in case of everything ran fine, I just want to write something like response.setData(data) and return the object. Otherwise the error handler would take care. Thanks for help.

Comment: Why does this look so much like trying to reinvent SOAP?

Comment: I like SOAP and it would be my first choice, however, the requirement is to be able to respon as XML, JSON, or whatever else...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [JAX-RS spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html) or Jersey User Guide especially section devoted to [JSON](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json) ([JAXB based JSON support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e6192)).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is to use JAXB to create the tooled version of the structure (with something like Jackson as the serialization engine) and then to create a factory method somewhere that will make the structure for you without you having to specify anything extra yourself.